# Saving Excel 2007 documents

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, office-2007

In .NET C# I'm trying to open an Excel template, add some data and save it as a new document.  I'm trying to use the OpenXML document format. I can't seem to find any guidance on how to do this.  Seems like all the documentation talks about how to write various parts to the Package but I can't find anything on what to do when you're done and want to save it.

Anyone know where I can find this information?  I must be thinking about this incorrectly because I'm not finding anything useful on what seems to be very basic.

Thanks

Comment: SpreadsheetML is _not_ OpemXML

Comment: @Joel - Actually, SpreadsheetML is used as the name for the Excel 2007 Open XML format, as well as the old deprecated Excel 2003 XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExcelPackage](http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelPackage) works pretty good for that.  It hasn't been worked on by the primary author I dont think for a little while but it has a good following of people on its forum that work any issues out.

```
            FileInfo template = new FileInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+"\\Template.xlsx");
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(strFileName,template))
            {
                //Enable DEBUG mode to create the xl folder (equlivant to expanding a xlsx.zip file)
                //xlPackage.DebugMode = true;

                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

                worksheet.Name = WorkSheetName;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int c = 1;
                    if (r > startRow) worksheet.InsertRow(r);
                    // our query has the columns in the right order, so simply
                    // iterate through the columns
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        if (row[col].ToString() != null)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cell(r, c).Value = colValue;
                            worksheet.Column(c).Width = 10;
                        }
                        c++;
                    }
                    r++;
                }

                // change the sheet view to show it in page layout mode
                worksheet.View.PageLayoutView = false;

                // save our new workbook and we are done!
                xlPackage.Save();
                xlPackage.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Open XML / SpreadsheetML documents is far from a trivial exercise. The specification is large and complex. The "Open XML SDK" (google it) definitely helps, but still requires some knowledge of the Open XML standard to get much done.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) has an API similar to Excel and can read and write Excel Open XML (xlsx) documents as well as Excel 97-2003 (xls) documents.

You can see some SpreadsheetGear samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC